# Override HttpServletResponse sendError or setStatus

Tags: java, servlets, jboss

I'm working on a project where we are migrating code from Jetty to Jboss. This code is used as an API where different services is calling the service, the service perform the operation and returns the data, but if something goes wrong during the process exceptions are thrown and finally caught in the top level class.

When using Jetty this worked good, hence the Jetty servlet engine added the message sent to the HttpServletResponse [sendError](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendError%28int,%20java.lang.String%29) function to the status line.
But in Jboss, the default status is instead added:

Jetty:
return: 500: My Custom error

Jboss: 500: Internal Server Error

I've not been able to add the *USE_CUSTOM_STATUS_MSG_IN_HEADER* to the Jboss, so I thought I might customize the response by creating a HttpServletResponseWrapper and overriding either the sendError or setStatus message to do what I need and return the content in a way I need it.

But, I'm unsure on how to perform this, or if there are any better solutions.

best,
Henrik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To wrap the HttpServletResponse, you'll want to create a [Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) that creates the HttpServletResponseWrapper and passes it down the chain instead of the original response passed to `doFilter(..)`:

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp, FilterChain chain) {
    HttpServletResponseWrapper wrapper = new MyHttpServletResponseWrapper(resp);
    chain.doFilter(req, wrapper);
}

private static class MyHttpServletResponseWrapper extends HttpServletResponseWrapper {
    ...
}
```

Comment: The trap is created, the problem is how to create the custom response, since I'm not using any JSP pages, do I only need to write to the outputstream and close the stream? And also, the setStatus method needs to be changed to I suppose...

Comment: well how to write the custom error page is up to your logic - if you just want to write out a string or some simple output, sure you can write directly to the outputstream...

Comment: Okay, so one does not need to set the status, you can just write to the stream and then close it when done to end the connection?

Comment: Solved it with the outputstream.
Thanks